# Find the fourier series of $\sin(x-\pi/6)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am asked to find the Fourier Series of $\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$

The question tells me that integration is not necessary and to use Trigonemetric Identities but i can't seem to figure out what trigonometric identity will help.

I have tried comparing this function $\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$
to $\sin(x)$ since the only difference is their period but i'm not quite sure if that's the right approach.

Secondly, is $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ odd and even respectively regardless of what's inside the paranthesis(as long as there's a variable $x$) ?

Comment: Use the sum identity for sin.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the Fourier series of a periodic function $f(x)$ is

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(a_n \cos \frac{2\pi n x}{L} + b_n \sin \frac{2\pi n x}{L}\right) \tag{1}
$$

where $L$ is the period of $f$. Now, use the fact that

$$
\sin(x - \pi/6) = \sin x \cos\frac{\pi}{6} - \cos x \sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin x - \frac{1}{2}\cos x \tag{2}
$$

If you compare (2) against (1) you will see that the series of $f(x) = \sin(x - \pi/6)$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
a_0 &=& 0 \\
a_1 &=& -1/2 \\
a_k &=& 0 ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ k=2,3,\cdots\\
b_1 &=& \sqrt{3}/2 \\
b_k &=& 0 ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ k=2,3,\cdots \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

and $L = 2\pi$